# Why has SoftBank increased less on the Frankfurt Stock Exchange than on the OTC market?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Living sometimes in Canada and sometimes in France, I use both Questrade and Degiro.

My question relates to the following stocks:

- OTCMKTS: SFTBY (*SoftBank* on **OTC Markets** - with Questrade)
- FRA: SFT (*SoftBank* on **Frankfurt Stock Exchange** - with Degiro)

I don't understand why these two stocks **didn't increase as much as each other**.
Aren't they supposed to **represent the same asset** on the Tokyo Stock Exchange?

From *19 Mar 2020* to *16 Feb 2021*

- SFTBY has increased by **285%**
- SFT has increased by **229%**

This makes a difference of **56%**, which seems a lot to me.
How can it be explained?

In your opinion, should the OTC market be preferred to foreign shares on the Frankfurt Stock Exchange? What are the **advantages/disadvantages** of one or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SFTBY is quoted in US dollars. SFT is quoted in euro. You’re seeing the effect of a change in the exchange rates between the two currencies during the period.

Comment: Interesting! Does this explain the totality of the 56% difference according to you? I just looked at the EUR / USD chart on Google, and the variation over this period is 14%.

Comment: You cannot subtract the increase percentages, that doesn’t give a useful number. Divide the final values: 385% by 329%, and you get about 117%, so the 17% would be the currency exchange impact.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. So the only factor explaining this difference according to you, comes from currency fluctuations? This difference being expressed by dividing one increase (in %) by the other (in %) ? Assuming a price change over this period, to avoid a division by zero.